# circuit for converting in 0-5v to 4-20mA current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, 4-20ma

basically is want to make a circuit that takes 0-5v input and converts it in and corresponding output current of 4-20mA using opamp , i have seen reference circuit from this pdf https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/D61_EN-Convert.pdf
but it has converted from 1-5v to 4-20mA current source
but i want to make a circuit that converts 0-5 to 4-20mA current source

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify whether the output of your circuit is source or sink. i.e., does it have to *supply* the current or *sink* it from somewhere else? Please capitalise properly for legibility and credibility.

Comment: @Transistor  it is a current source,sorry for mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just use your reference circuit (1-5V input) and convert your 0-5V input to 1-5V with two resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqbHq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't have a +5V rail, you can create an equivalent from any higher rail with a pair of resistors and a little math:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPbPDZ.png)</sup>

Comment: in the appnote circuit the second stage opamp is also given 24V?@td127

Comment: It's a dual opamp, so both stages have the same rails. So assuming you have this +24V fail as your VCC, the equations work out to R1=192K, R2=50.5K for R3 = 10K.  Using standard 1% values, R1=196K, R2=51.1K, R3=10.2K will get you pretty close.

Comment: oops, typo: I meant "+24V rail", not "+24V fail" !

Comment: thanks for help @td127

Comment: You have 2 equations and 2 unknowns (R1 and R2). In the diagram the "R1 || R2" means "R1 in parallel with R2", for which the equation is (R1 * R2) / (R1 + R2). You want this to equal 40K (or 4 times whatever R3 is). The other equation is [R2 / (R1+R2)] * VCC = 5, where VCC is your rail voltage. Let me know what you come up with and I'll check your math.

Comment: i got R2=68.91K and R1=96.4K, i also re-checked by calculating the Rth and Vth thanks for help@td127

Comment: Perfect! Now just nudge to the nearest legal 1% resistor values. You might get a better fit if you also nudge R3 (as I did, to 10.2K) but if you do that make sure Rth = 4 * R3.

Comment: okay,i will find the nearest resistor @td127

Answer (score 1):

Using your reference, the 1st stage converts 5V to 500 uA and the 2nd stage ratio of R4,R3 is 40:1 giving 0 to 20mA for 0 to 5V drop across the 10k. But then you need to add a 4mA offset with 0 to 16 mA.
But you also need ESD and transient protection.

So I recommend a better design.
[ref](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu299/tidu299.pdf?ts=1598635737295&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTIPD158)
[image]

Comment: thanks for help@Tony

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an integrated circuit designed for [this purpose](https://www.ti.com/product/XTR115) would be the easiest to use.
[image: 0v]

[image: 5v]

[image: 4-20ma]

Comment: The schematic gives little clue as to how the circuit works. Pin designations would be useful and some text.

Comment: The block [diagram](https://imgur.com/a/09wtdIr) is from the [pdf](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr115.pdf?ts=1598712989583&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FXTR115).

Comment: thanks for help@csabahu